# rootbeer and Nvidia Optimus

Tags: linux, optimus, rootbeer

Does the Java CUDA tool [rootbeer](https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1) work with [Nvidia Optimus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_Optimus) on Linux when the laptop does not have a BIOS switch for the graphics system?  In other words, does it work where the graphics system is always a hybrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it to run if you use `bumblebee` and `optirun`.  I did this from within Eclipse.  Threads will run to completion and in my tests, the computed results are the expected results.  Whether `numberOfJobs * elapsedTimePerJob / elapsedTime > 1.0` is a matter of experimentation and I found that often it is far less than 1.0.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284881/rootbeer-cuda-example-code-quantified-throughput-gain) for details on how to get good speedups. Or email me at pcpratts@trifort.org